# Typescript compiler is not detecting a missing import for lodash with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, types, compiler-errors

I'm trying to set up webpack with Typescript in my project using the [official tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/). Here is my folder structure and the important files:

```
├── dist
│   ├── bundle.js
│   └── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

`src/index.ts`:

```
// import _ from 'lodash';

const result = _.add(5, 6);
console.log(result);
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strict": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es5",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
  }
```

Notice that in `index.ts` that the import for lodash (I ran `npm i lodash @types/lodash`) is commented out. This should be a TS error, but this is what I see in VSCode:

[image: No error for missing import]

In addition, I am able to compile the project into a bundle by running `npx webpack` (`tsc src/index.ts` also works). However, when I open the file in the browser, I see this in the console:

[image: Lodash underscore not found ReferenceError]

Obviously, this shows that TS assumes `_` is defined globally (not sure how) even though the package isn't actually imported itself. Uncommenting the import fixes the ReferenceError, but I don't understand why the Typescript Compiler doesn't realize that lodash isn't imported and report a compile error.

One thing I did notice though, is that when I changed my file to the following, I got this warning with a squiggly red line under the underscore for `_.add`:

```
// import _ from 'lodash';
import a from 'lodash';

const result = _.add(5, 6);
console.log(result);
```

> '_' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead. ts(2686)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lodash typings declare that a global variable `_`. This means that as long as those typings are included in your project, TypeScript will pick up the global definition of `_`.

Additionally, the reason why you see a warning  when using `_` is module files (files that use `import` or `export`) is that accessing global in modules is often unexpected. The best practice is to always use proper imports

Comment: So would this be considered an error on the part of Lodash's developers? Because even though the typings are available, I shouldn't be able to use them unless I import them through the library, right?

Comment: No, this is intentional. There are still a lot of web devs who will import lodash with a `<script>` tag. Defining a global `_` supports use cases like that (but unfortunately it can cause confusion in cases where globals are not encouraged or will just not work)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Came across this tonight and decided to test whether the TypeScript compiler would let me use Lodash without importing it (because it would see the declared global variable from the types). I got this message: `'_' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)`. So it looks like the TypeScript compiler is smart enough to see that I already had imports and exports, and knew the proper way for me to use Lodash was to import it in my module.